# How do you find the name of the current namespace

Tags: apl, dyalog

I have been reading a lot about namespaces and there is one thing I cannot figure out. How do you get the name of the current namespace in Dyalog APL, similar to "pwd" in linux?

I would like to get the current NS programmatically in a function and on the command line.

Comment: By all means, ask questions on Stack Overflow, but note that for simple things like this, you can often [find the answer on APLcart](https://aplcart.info?q=current%20namespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`⎕THIS`](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/System%20Functions/this.htm)

That said, it actually returns a *reference* to the current namespace. If you want the name in text form, then use `⍕⎕THIS`, but note that a namespace can be unnamed, in which case you might get something useless like `'#.[Namespace]'`.

Comment: Thank you....now that I know this, I was able to find it in the documentation.